# How to let a wheel to rotate around its center in (GLUT) openGL without pressing any key or clicking the mouse button

Tags: opengl

I need to make this wheel to make a rotation animation around its center in openGL continuously without clicking the mouse,because the wheel makes its rotation if the left button of the mouse is clicked!!, this is the wheel:

[image]

This is the code I used to draw the wheel and to make the rotation:

```
#include <freeglut.h>

#include <glaux.h>


void whiteStud()

{


        glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        glutSolidSphere(0.01, 16, 16);


}

void blackWheel() 

{


       glColor3f(0.129412, 0.129412, 0.129412);
       glutSolidSphere(0.1, 16, 16);


}


void wheelWithStuds()

   {  
       /**********************************/
        int iTimeElapsed = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
        float fScale= 0.5f;
        long i;
       /**********************************/
       /* clear all pixels */
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
       /**********************************/
       glPushMatrix();
       glTranslatef(0.25, 0.25, 0.0);
       glRotatef(iTimeElapsed * fScale,0.0,0.0,1.0);
       blackWheel(); // draw the wheel without studs.
       /**********************************/
       // five studs, step 72 degree (72*5=360 degree).
       for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
            glPushMatrix();
            glRotatef(72*i,0.0,0.0,1.0); // rotate coordinate 72 degree.
            glTranslatef(0.04, 0.0, 0.0);// translate on the rotated coordinate.
            whiteStud(); // draw the stud.
            glPopMatrix();
            } 
            glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);// translate in order to draw a stud at the center of the wheel.
            whiteStud();// draw the stud at the center of the wheel.
            /**********************************/
            /* don't wait! start processing buffered OpenGL routines */
            glFlush();
            glPopMatrix();
            /**********************************/

   }


int main(int argc, char** argv)

   {
      glutInit(&argc, argv);
      glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
      glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
      glutInitWindowPosition(10, 10);
      glutCreateWindow("(-Rotating Car Wheel-)");
      /* select clearing (background) color */
      glClearColor(1.0, 1.0,1.0, 1.0);
      /* initialize viewing values */
      glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
      glLoadIdentity();
      glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
      glLoadIdentity();
      glutDisplayFunc(wheelWithStuds);
      glutMainLoop();
      return 0;
   }
```

I want this wheel to rotate by itself without clicking the left button of the mouse, how can I perform this?

Comment: At first,draw wheel at the origin then rotate it and translate it where you want to render.

Comment: You need to add glutPostRedisplay() to the end of draw_wheel(). I mention this in my answer below. You also do not need glFlush().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a new draw_wheel() with the desired motion. Notably, you forgot `glutPostRedisplay()` at the end of the draw method; this function tells glut to redraw the window. Also you were not resetting your first call to `glTranslatef()`, so every time you clicked the window the object got further away from its original position.

```
void draw_wheel()
{  
    int iTimeElapsed = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME);
    float fRevolveScale1 = 0.2f;
    float fRevolveScale2 = 0.4f;
    long i;

    // clear all pixels
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // push temp state
    glPushMatrix();

    // translate to center
    glTranslatef(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0); 

    // rotate around pivot
    glRotatef(iTimeElapsed * fRevolveScale1,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    // translate to planet location
    glTranslatef(0.25f, 0.25f, 0.0); 

    glRotatef(iTimeElapsed * fRevolveScale2,0.0,0.0,1.0);

    glColor3f(0.129412f, 0.129412f, 0.129412f);
    glutSolidSphere(0.1f, 16, 16);

    // five bolts, step 72 degree (72*5=360 degree)
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    for(i=0; i<5; ++i) 
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glRotatef(72.0f*i,0.0,0.0,1.0); // rotate coordinate 72 degree
        glTranslatef(0.04f, 0.0, 0.0);// translate on the rotated coordinate
        glutSolidSphere(0.01f, 16, 16);
        glPopMatrix();
    }

    glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);// translate on the rotated coordinate
    glutSolidSphere(0.01, 16, 16);

    // pop temp state
    glPopMatrix();

    glFlush();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: Are you rotating the object around the center of the window, or rotating around the center of the object, or both? Also, what's currently happening?

Comment: I updated the draw_wheel() with what I believe you want. Let me know if that's not exactly it.